# ICP - add ldap ends with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I fail to configure openldap as team directory in IBM Cloud Private (Community Edition). In the logs I see the following:

Exiting directory-util:configureWithData with errorError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3100

Everything else works as expected. Deployment of Helm charts, Scaling up/down....only the LDAP part is missing.

Thx4Help
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give us more information or logs to debug this issue? You can run below commands to collect related pods logs, thanks.

kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep auth-idp

kubectl -n kube-system logs auth-idp-xxxxx -c platform-identity-mgmt

kubectl -n kube-system logs auth-idp-xxxxx -c platform-identity-provider

kubectl -n kube-system logs auth-idp-xxxxx -c platform-auth-service

Note: please replace the auth-idp-xxxxx with the exact name get by 1st command.

Comment: Hi, I removed the existing pod auth-idp-xxxxx and the new one now seems to work. Thx